# How do I make a json request to a rails 3 website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I know that if I have a url like

```
mysite/posts/1
```

The default type returned to me is html. I can get an xml version of the resource by just doing

```
mysite/posts/1.xml
```

But how do I get a json version? Is the following supposed to work?

```
mysite/posts/1.json
```

Reason I ask is because it doesn't seem to be working. So I figured I should find out if it's "supposed" to work this way before investigating further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing it right, but if the Controller isn't setup to respond to json requests you won't get anything. You'll have a respond_to block like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.xml { render :xml => @model_var.to_xml }
  format.json { render :json => @model_var.to_json } #without this line, .json requests will go unanswered by the web server.
end
```

Comment: You don't even need `to_json` and `to_xml`, because Rails (at last new releases of Rails) automatically call this methods if object passed is not string.

Comment: So under Rails 3 it looks the same, except for the method calls on the model variable?

Comment: That's right. You just need to pass model (or collection if I remember correctly)